# How do I check out what was in my git repository N days ago?

Tags: git

I have to check out my source code from two days ago.  Whenever I have to do this, I have to look up the syntax.  It's not in the git-checkout page.  I'd like to have a convenient Stack Overflow question to refer to so I don't have to look it up every time.  If this has already been asked, please point me to the dupe. :)

How do I check out my source code in git from two (or N) days ago?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
git checkout @{two.days.ago}
```

Comment: Note that this command would checkout what you had checked out in **your** repository two days ago; it is local repository only information.  See "Specifying revisions" section in [`git rev-parse`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) documentation; it uses *reflog*

Answer (score 28):

All of these work (because git is pretty smart):

```
git checkout @{yesterday}
git checkout @{2.days.ago}
git checkout @{'2 days ago'}
git checkout @{'5 minutes ago'}
git checkout @{'1 month 2 weeks 3 days 1 hour 1 second ago'}
git checkout any-branch-name@{'1 hour ago'}
```

As @Jakub Narębski noted in his comment, these are references to your *local* repository at that time. More info in the Specifying Revisions section of the `git rev-parse` docs [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions).