# Git checkout repository from N days ago

Tags: git, date, git-checkout

How can I check out a git repository using time notation such as "3 days ago", "12 months ago", etc?

Note [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052854/how-do-i-check-out-what-was-in-my-git-repository-n-days-ago) only concerns the local repo, but I want to inspect the remote  repo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[git checkout by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990484/git-checkout-by-date) gives me

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="3 days ago" master`
```

Comment: The OP wanted to explicitly inspect the remote rather than the local master branch.

Comment: @mockinterface Unlike your answer, this one will (mostly) do the right thing if you replace "master" by "origin/master".

Comment: Of course, but the OP already has in mind the notation that he wants to use, and the answer should explain how to apply it to a remote branch. At the very least it should indeed use origin/master instead of master, and explain that fetching is necessary.

Comment: This worked for me, and I edited the answer to include `3 days ago` notation. Thanks for pointing it out @hvd.